# Interactive sorting in Reporting service fails with rsReportNotReady exception in SSRS 2008 Report Service

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am working on SSRS reprting Service 2008 and added subscriptions. But in HTML 4.0 format when I try to click on sorting the error shows; **The selected report is not ready for viewing. The report is still being rendered or a report snapshot is not available**

I have already set SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION OFF. But still facing same problem.

Comment: Can you provide the log please?